# what does Hartshorne mean by 'lifting' of a section of a sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In his proof of proposition 2.5.6 on pg. 113 Hartshorne seems to use the term lift in two different ways. Fist he seems to use it in the context of surjectivity of a map of sheaves: In the sense that $s$ is locally the image of sections of $\mathcal{F}$. Then immediately after he uses it to describe a section 'lifting' to a global section on the same sheaf. In both cases it seems to describe a section lying in the set theoretic image of a map, but in the first case the map is a map of sheaves and in the other its a restriction map. Is this use of terminology correct or consistent throughout the book?

Edit: Further in the proof he uses the term extends' to destine a section lifting to a section on a larger open set of the same sheaf. This seems to indicate his usage is in fact inconsistent

Comment: Hartshorne is someone's name, so we write it with a capital H and try not to misspell it in a title! He wrote more than one book, so when we talk about one of them we usually say which one we have in mind.

Comment: In the second instance he's using the word lifting to mean that something is in the image of the restriction map, no? Usually something 'lifts' if it is in the image of some function, but this idea is very, very flexible... He is not inconsistent: he is a human writing to humans, so wants not to bore people to death by repetition. There is no rule that everything has to be said all the time in the same form always!

Comment: I have a hard time minding if OP capitalizes Hartshorne's name since Hartshorne does not capitalize any proper noun containing 'Noetherian' in the entirety of Algebraic Geometry text. For some reason all of the proper nouns containing 'Riemann', 'Zariski', and 'Grothendieck' got capitalized, however.

Comment: You should write to Hartshone an email, I am sure he'll very interested in your observations — and they might even be on topic there!